# Get and show direction without showing a google map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

Hi is it possible to get the direction from googlemaps without showing a map?

I can get the directions from calling like this:-

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=52.4076963,-1.4853391999999985&destination=52.6114729,-1.6812878000000637&key=KEYHERE

<div id="result"></div>
```

And the code I am trying to call it with is :

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = "52.4076963,-1.4853391999999985";
    var end = "52.6114729,-1.6812878000000637";
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            result.innerHTML= "";
            for (var i =0; i < response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++){
                result.innerHTML+=response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].instructions+"<br>"
            }
            console.log(response)
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

calcRoute();
```

How I get this to run with calcRoute and just show the direction in the div?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the directions text without a map using the Google Maps Javascript API v3:

1. don't set the `map` property of the `DirectionsRenderer`
2. set the `panel` property of the `DirectionsRenderer`

```
function calcRoute() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var start = "52.4076963,-1.4853391999999985";
  var end = "52.6114729,-1.6812878000000637";
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('result'));
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ju6h0qw9/1/)

```js
function initialize() {
  function calcRoute() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var start = "52.4076963,-1.4853391999999985";
    var end = "52.6114729,-1.6812878000000637";
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('result'));
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }

  calcRoute();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to a lot of "how to use the maps API without showing a map?" questions assumes that it's going to be ok to use setPanel and for a journey plan to appear on your page instead of a map.

In case anyone wondered, if you don't want this and just want to extract data from the API without any google html being injected into your page at all you still need to use setPanel, but parse a null to it.

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
```